# Usar str_replace para substituir valores da variavel chave

Tags: php

Boa noite pessoal! Estou tentando utilizar o método `str_replace()` para substituir um termo dentro de uma variável, mas não está tendo efeito.

```
foreach ($paginas as $pagina => $codigo) {

    if(!strcasecmp($atual, $pagina)) {

        str_replace("nav-link", "nav-link active", $codigo);

    }

    //Ao imprimir aqui, a substituição não surte efeito
    echo $codigo;

}
```

Eu pensei que seria porque a variavel `$codigo`, que é a variavel que o foreach usa para atribuir o valor atual não aceita modificações, mas talvez eu esteja errado, então vim perguntá-los.

Comment: AH, correto. Agora fui ler sobre o método no site do PHP e vi que a função retorna uma string ou array com os valores substituidos. Como eu vim do Java, achei que o método funcionava como o replace(), sem dar retorno. Obrigado por exclarecer.

Comment: Fica a dica de acompanhar sempre o manual do PHP, pq como você está acostumado com Java (que é um pouco mais consistente em termos de nomenclatura) vai ter muitas surpresas, principalmente quanto às ordens dos parâmetros (que variam muito em PHP, muitas vezes na mesma família de funções).

Comment: Pois é. Eu tinha lido sobre esse método no manual do PHP, mas não tinha botado atenção na parte do retorno.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O correto seria isso:

```
$codigo = str_replace('nav-link', 'nav-link active', $codigo);
```

A razão é que o *replace* não é feito na *string* original. É criada uma nova *string* com o valor alterado, que é retornada pela função.

Veja uma demonstração:

> http://ideone.com/m4jXYN

Não relacionado ao seu caso específico, mas vale notar que você pode fazer várias substituições com um `str_replace` só, passando *arrays* em vez de *strings* nos parâmetros.

Adicionalmente, se der preferência a aspas simples em *strings* no PHP, evitará um *parse* desnecessário na busca de caracteres especiais e interpolação de parâmetros.

Veja mais detalhes sobre o `str_replace` no manual:

> https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php